# D3js force-directed graph with zoom crashes in MD Edge when introducing markers

Tags: javascript, zooming, microsoft-edge, d3-force-directed

I am trying to make a force-directed graph using D3JS with pan and zoom. The graph works fine until I introduce markers to make link arrow ends. When I do so it works fine in chrome, firefox, and safari, but the graph crashes when I scale zoom in MS Edge. If you look at this fiddle:
https://codepen.io/aschultz/pen/gQJaKb
lines 140-152 add the arrows

```
var arrows = g.append("svg:defs")
    .attr("class","arrows")
    .append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -10 20 20")
    .attr("refX", 33)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 10)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-10 L 20 0L0,10");
link.attr('marker-end', "url(#arrow)")
```

This fiddle will crash on zoom in MS Edge. But if you comment out line 152 before zooming:
https://codepen.io/aschultz/pen/LXopOX

```
//link.attr('marker-end', "url(#arrow)")
```

Then it works fine, but obviously you don't get the arrows. One workaround is to replace the markers by paths themselves:
https://codepen.io/aschultz/pen/eQaBBm
But then you obviously lose a lot of the nice things about markers, and the math is going to get trickier if you start making paths that aren't straight. Any suggestions on how to make this work with markers on Edge?

The fiddle was modified from Tom Roth's example: https://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/4438752bb93f45dc5ad5214efaa12e4a
Other modifications include changing the links to path from lines:

```
//.enter().append("line") to
.enter().append("svg:path")
```

And then change link actions to deal with path:

```
//link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
//.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
//.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
//.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; }); to
link.attr("d",function(d){return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" +
 d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;})
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, I have tested your sample code on my Edge browser (Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134), the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnjXh.gif), it seems that everything works well. So, please check your Edge browser version.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge 41.16299.785.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299. When I try to zoom with the markers it just auto refreshes. Looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/2lBrFNo)